# Kotlin array of properties with custom getters

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Say I have this:

```
class NumWithSuccessor {
    var num = 1
    val successor
        get() = num + 1
}
```

Now, if I want an array of `num`s instead,

```
class NumsWithSuccessors {
    var nums = Array<Int>(3){ 1 }
    val successor
        get() = /* What? */
}
```

My first guess is to use

```
get() = { Array<Int>(3){ nums[it] + 1 } }
```

But that would lead to creation of a new array every time I need to access a successor. **Is there a simple, better way?**

Practical Example:

```
// Need to go from this...
private val _dayWiseEventsList =             // For internal use
        MediatorLiveData<List<Event>>()

val dayWiseEventsList: LiveData<List<Event>> // For immutable, external observation
        get() = _dayWiseEventsList


// ... to this
private val _dayWiseEventsListArray =        // For internal use
        Array<MediatorLiveData<List<Event>>>(DAYS) { MediatorLiveData() }

val dayWiseEventsListArray                   // For immutable, external observation
        // Need an alternative for this
        get() = Array<LiveData<List<Event>>>(DAYS) { _dayWiseEventsListArray[it] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can lazily initialize it:

```
val successor by lazy { Array<Int>(3){ nums[it] + 1 } }
```

This will create the array only once when it is first accessed, then it will return the same array on subsequent accesses.

However note that this will not update `successor` in case you modify `nums`. If you want to update it you will need to set a customer setter for `nums` and update `successor` accordingly.

---

Like I explained in the comments, I would make all this immutable, for example:

```
data class NumsWithSuccessors(val nums: List<Int> = List(3){ 1 }) {
    val successor by lazy { nums.map { it + 1 } }
}
```

Comment: The only downside here is that array is mutable, the `successor` will share that array outside, where it can be changed. Kotlin List<T> will be more safe here

Comment: @EugenePetrenko I totally agree, however OP is using arrays and asking arrays.

Comment: I'd say your solution is a big downside if `successor` must be dependent on `nums` not only during first access.

Comment: @Sergey Yes, however it is the OP that has put those restrictions. There's no way to actually solve his problem without making everything immutable, which is what I would do.

Comment: @Sergey It is not wrong, it does answer OP's question with the required restrictions. Is it correct? No. Is it how I would do it? Definitely not. But I can't fix without removing the question restrictions, which I already state in my answer.

Comment: I guessed it was obvious from the example, but I do require `successors` to have the correct value at a given index whenever accessed, which would be the *then* value at that index of `nums` + 1. Kind of an array of getters, if you will.

Comment: @aksh1618 Then like I said you need a setter for `nums` that will update `successors` every time it changes. I personally recommend a more immutable approach, where you declare `NumWithSuccessor` as a data class, create a new instance of it with new `nums` value instead of modifying the internal state of an existing instance. This gets rid of your problem, simplifies the code, and avoids internal mutable state.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
class NumsWithSuccessors {
    var nums: List<Int> = List(3){ 1 }
    val successors: List<Int> = object: AbstractList<Int>() {
        override val size get() = nums.size
        override fun get(index: Int) = nums[index] + 1;
    }
}
```

In the above example, `successors` is a virtual `List` that doesn't actually contain data. When you try to read an item from `successors`, it simply looks at the underlying `nums` list to calculate the value. The `AbstractList` class deals with providing implementations for all the other list behaviour, based on the `get` and `size` implementations you supply.

This works with a `List`, but not with an `Array`. An array can't have custom behaviour; it's a primitive data type that just stores values. `List` is an interface, the underlying behaviour of which can be modified at will.

Answer (score 0):

`successor` can't depend on `nums`, has `val` modifier and use cached array at the same time. The solution is to create a new list using `map` function every time `successor` property is accessed:

```
class NumWithSuccessor {
    var nums = Array<Int>(3){ 1 }
    val successor
        get() = nums.map { it + 1 }
}
```

Comment: Still creates a new list every time it is called.

Comment: I guess in this case new array always should be created.

Comment: @m0skit0, you can create a setter for nums, and set successor value inside it using map operator. It prevents from creating a new array every time.

Comment: @MamykinAndrey Right, you can post that answer :)

Comment: but a new list is also created in that case :)

Comment: additional we need to change `val` to `var` of `successor`

Comment: > still creates a new list
The list you create depends on the `nums` variable, which is also mutable. Caching 
it may harm at some point
If you indeed want it to cache, you may remove `get() = ` from the declaration. It will create a property with the value, that is computed when an instance is created

Comment: @EugenePetrenko Exactly, in fact successor is not really a field but more of a property/function that is in function of `nums` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a setter for nums, and set successor value inside it using `map` operator. It prevents from creating a new array every time:

```
class NumsWithSuccessors {
    var successor: Array<Int> = arrayOf()
    var nums: Array<Int> = Array(3) { 1 }
    set(value) {
        field = value; successor = value.map { it + 1 }.toTypedArray()
    }
```

Comment: New list is also created in that case :). `value.map` creates a new list. Also the downside is that you need to change `val` modifier to `var`, and `successor` will be eligible for changing from outside.